# API to import collection and environment to postman

Tags: api, postman, pipeline, newman

is there a way to import to our private workspace new environment files using an api for a CI/CD process?

Answer (score 0):

You can the Postman API to import OpenAPI definitions by POSTing a file or string to the **import/{{importType}}** [endpoint](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/631643/JsLs/#09886971-e1e2-4a62-8f59-f7abfd79ff5e) and appending `/?workspace={workspaceId}` to the url.

The workspace parameter isn't documented.