# Import postman collection using postman API

Tags: automation, postman

I'm trying to create a shell script to import collection to postman using the postman API. I saw that they have mentioned the api to create collection in the [postman API collection](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/request/12959542-049042b8-447f-4f71-8b79-ae978cf40a04), but I'm not sure what to use for the schema in the payload.

I also checked the question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59500629/api-to-import-collection-and-environment-to-postman) but seems like the documentation is already outdated and no longer available.

Comment: Can you expand on the reason for wanting to import a Collection file that way? An example of the payload for the Create Collection endpoint is under the same request you linked. https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/example/12959542-5c3ee5b8-4363-4ee3-99bb-314a012b1ed1

Comment: I already solved this issue and thanks for the comment. The purpose of this is me and my team is creating a shared postman collection for the team. But for us the postman enterprise license is not an option for synching and have to do it using GitHub. So I was building a shell script that can automatically drop the current collection and import the collection in GitHub flow. Also I managed to create a script for exporting your postman collection to GitHub. So the team don't have to manually do the process each time.

Comment: If you have a team of 3 people, you could collaborate on that Collection from the same Team Workspace, without needing to Export or import anything. You could also make you of the Postman API with would give you the most upto date version of that collection with needing to export/import.